# CSS div box animation with elastic effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Hey all i have a JSFiddle of what i am trying to accomplish here > [JSFIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/HRGKq/13/)

Problem being is that i am unsure on how to go about giving it the elastic effect when opening and when closing back down to a smaller square. However, currently its going crazy once you hover over it :o). It also seems to push the text inside all crazy as it re-sizes. How can i just have the text appear the same no matter the shape the box goes to?

The JS code:

```
$('#menuSquare').mouseover(function() {
    $('#menuSquare').animate({
        width: "95",
        height: "400",
        padding: '20',
        opacity: 0.8
    }, 1000)
});

$('#menuSquare').mouseout(function() {
    $('#menuSquare').animate({
        width: "20",
        height: "20",
        opacity: 0.4
    }, 1000)
});
```

​The HTML:

```
<div id="menuSquare" class="TheMenuBox">
      <p><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#666;">Category 1</a></p>
      <p><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#666;">Category 2</a></p>
      <p><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#666;">Category 2</a></p>
</div>​
```

The CSS:

```
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#666;
}
body {
    background-color: #0CF;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.TheMenuBox {
    position:absolute; 
    background-color:#FFF; 
    width: 20px; /* 95 */
    display:block; 
    height: 20px;
    top:16px; 
    left:260px; 
    opacity:0.40; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
    z-index:1000; 
    padding:0px; /* 20 */
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    text-decoration:none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

​Could anyone help out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the content of the box to absolute - I did this by wrapping the content in a div with a class called inner

```
.inner {position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px; width:95px;}
```

and add a .stop() before your .animate calls to stop them firing while another is trying to animate the opposite way.

```
$('#menuSquare').stop().animate({
```

See my fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/HRGKq/9/

Matt

Comment: Thanks for that, Matt. Anyway to use the easing effects on that?

Comment: Stealth was on the right track http://jsfiddle.net/HRGKq/16/ just add an easing style after the animate speed `.animate({}, 1000,'easeOutElastic')` along with the jquery ui library.